# How to start/stop nt-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter manually

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

How to customize start/stop of aws s3 inbound-channel-adapter . I want to set auto-startup="false" initially and start manually when server starts.Looking for a solution which is similar like we have the below solution for file inbound channel adaptor.

inboundFileAdapterChannel.send(new GenericMessage("@'s3FilesChannelId.adapter'.start()"));

Config:

If i try the same approach for s3 inbound adapter channel . I am getting the below error

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

A component required a bean named 's3FilesChannelId.adapter' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 's3FilesChannelId.adapter' in your configuration.

Comment: You need to show your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume we have a channel adapter like this:

```
<int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter id="s3Inbound"
                                    channel="s3Channel"
                                    session-factory="s3SessionFactory"
                                    auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                    auto-startup="false"
                                    delete-remote-files="true"
                                    preserve-timestamp="true"
                                    filename-pattern="*.txt"
                                    local-directory="."
                                    remote-file-separator="\"
                                    local-filename-generator-expression="#this.toUpperCase() + '.a' + @fooString"
                                    comparator="comparator"
                                    temporary-file-suffix=".foo"
                                    local-filter="acceptAllFilter"
                                    remote-directory-expression="'foo/bar'">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Pay attention to the `auto-startup="false"` and to the `id="s3Inbound"`.

So, it isn't going to be started automatically after application context initialization.
However using that `s3Inbound` id we can do that manually whenever it is convenient for us.

Your story about `inboundFileAdapterChannel` is not clear though, but you still can inject a `Lifecycle` for the mentioned channel adapter and perform its `start()`:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("s3Inbound")
private Lifecycle s3Inbound;

...

this.s3Inbound.start();
```

The piece of code about `inboundFileAdapterChannel` seems like a reference to the `Control Bus` approach, but that's already slightly different story: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#control-bus

Comment: Than you very much Artem. It is working as expected.